# use an arrayList as a source for a repeat control in XPages

Tags: java, xpages, repeat

I have developed a java Bean called payObj which is defined as a `HashMap<String, PaymentItem>` where PaymentItem is a class that defines a number of fields related to each individual payment. payObj is initially populated from a number related Notes documents. All of that works great. I have a method in the payObj.allItems() which returns an ArrayList of PaymentItem(s) -- perhaps there is a better way to get them but this works for now :

```
public ArrayList<PaymentItem> allItems(){
    ArrayList<PaymentItem> rtn = new ArrayList<PaymentItem>();
    try{
        for (Integer n = 1; n <= internalMap.size(); n++) {
            String thisKey = n.toString();
            PaymentItem pItem = this.internalMap.get((thisKey ).toString());
            if (debug) System.out.println("Copy item key = " + thisKey );
            rtn.add((n - 1),pItem);
        }
        if (debug) System.out.println("Return allItems " + rtn.toString());
        return rtn;
    }catch(Exception e){
        rtn = null;
        System.out.println("Error in PaymentMap allItems " + e.toString());
        return rtn;
    }
}
```

Edit --- I changed the allItems and added some additional output:

```
public ArrayList<PaymentItem> allItems(){
        ArrayList<PaymentItem> rtn = new ArrayList<PaymentItem>();
        try{
            for (Integer n = 1; n <= internalMap.size(); n++) {
                String thisKey = n.toString();
                PaymentItem pItem = new PaymentItem();
                pItem =  this.internalMap.get((thisKey ).toString());
                if (debug) System.out.println("Copy item key = " + pItem.getExpPayDate().toString() );
                rtn.add((n - 1),pItem);
            }
            for (Integer n = 0; n< rtn.size(); n++){
                if (debug) System.out.println("dates from ArrayList = " + rtn.get(n).getExpPayDate().toString());
            }
            if (debug) System.out.println("Return allItems " + rtn.toString());
            return rtn;
        }catch(Exception e){
            rtn = null;
            System.out.println("Error in PaymentMap allItems " + e.toString());
            return rtn;
        }
    }
```

and get this output in the log:

```
10/09/2015 01:21:04 PM  HTTP JVM: Copy item key = Thu Sep 24 12:00:00 MDT 2015
10/09/2015 01:21:04 PM  HTTP JVM: Copy item key = Sat Sep 05 12:00:00 MDT 2015
10/09/2015 01:21:04 PM  HTTP JVM: Copy item key = Fri Aug 28 12:00:00 MDT 2015
10/09/2015 01:21:04 PM  HTTP JVM: dates from ArrayList = Thu Sep 24 12:00:00 MDT 2015
10/09/2015 01:21:04 PM  HTTP JVM: dates from ArrayList = Sat Sep 05 12:00:00 MDT 2015
10/09/2015 01:21:04 PM  HTTP JVM: dates from ArrayList = Fri Aug 28 12:00:00 MDT 2015
10/09/2015 01:21:04 PM  HTTP JVM: Return allItems [ca.wfsystems.core.PaymentItem@39393939, ca.wfsystems.core.PaymentItem@4ef64ef6, ca.wfsystems.core.PaymentItem@51ca51ca]
```

So it sure looks like the ArrayList is populated correctly.

End Edit ------

I then use payObj.allItems() as the source for a repeat control:

```
<xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" var="pItem"
    indexVar="rIndex" value="#{javascript:payObj.allItems()}">
    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField5"
            value="#{javascript:pItem.expPayDate}">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertDateTime type="date"></xp:convertDateTime>
    </xp:this.converter>
    </xp:text>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
</xp:repeat>
```

When the repeat calls payObj.allItems() I get this printout in the log:

```
10/09/2015 10:01:32 AM  HTTP JVM: Copy item key = 1
10/09/2015 10:01:32 AM  HTTP JVM: Copy item key = 2
10/09/2015 10:01:32 AM  HTTP JVM: Copy item key = 3
10/09/2015 10:01:32 AM  HTTP JVM: Return allItems [ca.wfsystems.core.PaymentItem@4e664e66, ca.wfsystems.core.PaymentItem@52aa52aa, ca.wfsystems.core.PaymentItem@543a543a]
```

and this looks correct and identifies the 3 PaymentItem(s);

The getter and setter are:

```
public Date getExpPayDate() {
        return expPayDate;
    }

public void setExpPayDate(Date expPayDate) {
        this.expPayDate = expPayDate;
    }
```

However, while the repeat displays 3 lines  (as it should) it displays the date from the last Item 3 times rather than the different date in each pItem:

displays

Aug 28, 2015
Aug 28, 2015
Aug 28, 2015

instead of

Sep 15, 2015
Sept 4, 2015
Aug 28, 2015

Comment: If you add a sysout to the getExtPayDate method, does it print out the different values as expected? It could be that, though they are three distinct objects, the setting of expPayDate is incorrect.

Comment: BTW there is a quicker way to get a Map as ArrayList. 
return new ArrayList<PaymentItem>(internalMap,values())

Nevertheless is it strange about the Date, so I agree with Jesse, try as cyst

Comment: I added some println in the allItems to print the date while loading then loop through the arrayList after and the ArrayList looks to be loaded correctly

Comment: @BillF An aside: since you mentioned it's a bean, to keep with bean conventions, you would want  your property to be called allItems, with a public getter, e.g.- `getAllItems()` (as opposed to a method called `allItems()`). In your binding, instead of a `value="#{javascript:payObj.allItems()}"` in your `xp:repeat`, you can then bind it via EL, with `value="#{payObj.allItems}"`. It's the more accepted Java bean convention, though what you're doing works.

Comment: Your code works perfect for me.

Comment: This is one of those things that drives you up the wall. I changed the binding on the computed Text field of the repeat to EL and it started to work fine. Changed it back to JS binding and gave me all the same date for all three items. Changed it back to EL still did not work. Deleted the computed text field and created it new with the binding of EL and it works. So now to move on to the next step and see if that breaks it. and @EricMcCormick when I have the processes working I will go back and do as you say. Plus there are some ideas on how to load the ArrayList better as well.
Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

By the way, check out entrySet and keySet to get a better way to loop through a Map. I assume you want to just get all the key values in your Map? These return a set of entries or keys which you can loop through.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See my edits above. Not sure what caused the problem but it seems to be resolved. It is now working as shown